# How to negate or minimize repeating database records(rows) with several "many to many" relationships

Tags: database, database-design, many-to-many

I am pretty new to database development and architecture. My only experience has been in college and now my project requires me to use that knowledge, however my project seems a lot more complicated with many more intricacies than what I studied.

A brief overview: My task is to basically turn paper work that was previously done by hand, into a quick computer application, which I will do in Java but thats far off now. I know I will need a database set up to accomplish my task since these reports are frequently edited. The report is a *Labor Report*. Basically, it shows who was working on a specific job, what days and how many hours on those days, as well as their total hours, pay rate, and total amount.

I believe my current problem lies within the fact that it seems like I'm going to have several "many to many" relationships, perhaps even nested, which is what is throwing my head for a spin as I try to organize information into entity relationship diagrams and tables. (I know that there are normally much more measured and organized stages to development but I don't have that experience and I'm essentially a one man team on this)

Contract Personnel with be selected out of a pool of Employees.

A **Labor Contract** can have **1** to **10 personnel** (For sake of space on the final printed version, jobs requiring more laborers will have another Labor Contract.)

Each **personnel** must have **1** Title (foreman, mechanic, etc.) *These titles can change from job to job. Joe Smith can be a mechanic on job A but a foreman on job B*.
Each **personnel** *must* also have on record the number of hours they worked on each day of the week; and *may* have overtime and double overtime. (One Labor Record per week).

I am trying to avoid repeated data, or at least keep it to a minimum but I am struggling on figuring out how to do that in this situation. The tricky thing, at least in my mind, is figuring out how to handle the fact that different employees can work several jobs at once, under different titles, and different pay rates, and recording different types of hours (straight time, OT, double OT) on each day of the week.

Can anyone make suggestions?

I hope that I have supplied adequate information and apologize if I didn't or wasn't detailed enough. Please remember to keep in mind I'm a newbie to this type of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is a basic outline you could use to get started. Your final solution will be different based on your exact needs.

You'll need a table to store contract information. My example just shows a description but I'm sure you'll have much more than that.

```
contracts
    id              unsigned int(P)
    description     varchar(50)

+----+-------------+
| id | description |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Contract A  |
|  2 | Contract B  |
| .. | ........... |
+----+-------------+
```

You'll need a table that links contracts and employees and shows what title the employee has for the given contract. In my example you can see that for Contract A John Q Public is a Foreman and Mary Jane Smith is a Mechanic. For Contract B their titles are reversed, John is a Mechanic and Mary is a Foreman. `contract_id` and `employee_id` are foreign keys to their respective tables and together they form the primary key. If it's possible that John and Mary get paid different rates for the same title (for example John get 25.00/hour as Foreman while Mary gets 20.00/hour) you would add a column here instead of using the rate in the `titles` table.

```
contracts_employees
    contract_id     unsigned int(F contracts.id)--\_(P)
    employee_id     unsigned int(F employees.id)--/
    title_id        varchar(15)(F titles.id)

+-------------+-------------+----------+
| contract_id | employee_id | title_id |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
|           1 |           1 | Foreman  |
|           1 |           2 | Mechanic |
|           2 |           1 | Mechanic |
|           2 |           2 | Foreman  |
| ........... | ........... | ........ |
+-------------+-------------+----------+
```

You'll need a table for employees (you could call this personnel if you prefer). You'll probably store a lot more than just their names...

```
employees
    id              unsigned int(P)
    first_name      varchar(30)
    middle_name     varchar(30)
    last_name       varchar(30)
    ...

+----+------------+-------------+-----------+-----+
| id | first_name | middle_name | last_name | ... |
+----+------------+-------------+-----------+-----+
|  1 | John       | Quincy      | Public    | ... |
|  2 | Mary       | Jane        | Smith     | ... |
| .. | .......... | ........... | ......... | ... |
+----+------------+-------------+-----------+-----+
```

You'll need a table to track hours worked. I just store a beginning and ending date/time, leaving it up to the application to calculate elapsed time. Your application will also need to ensure there is no overlap for employees - an employee should not be able to be working on more than one contract at any given time. Calculation of overtime and double overtime hours is also up to your application. If an employee's pay rate can change at any time (ie in the middle of a contract) you would want to store the pay rate in this table instead of using the rate from `contracts_employees` or `titles`.

```
hours
    id              unsigned int(P)
    contract_id     unsigned int(F contracts.id)
    employee_id     unsigned int(F employees.id)
    beg             datetime
    end             datetime

+----+-------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | contract_id | employee_id | beg                 | end                 |
+----+-------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |           1 |           1 | 2014-01-01 08:00:00 | 2014-01-01 17:00:00 |
|  2 |           1 |           2 | 2014-01-01 09:00:00 | 2014-01-01 17:30:00 |
|  3 |           1 |           1 | 2014-01-02 09:00:00 | 2014-01-02 10:00:00 |
|  4 |           1 |           2 | 2014-01-02 08:00:00 | 2014-01-02 09:00:00 |
|  5 |           2 |           1 | 2014-01-02 10:00:00 | 2014-01-02 17:30:00 |
|  6 |           2 |           2 | 2014-01-02 09:00:00 | 2014-01-02 15:00:00 |
| .. | ........... | ........... | ................... | ................... |
+----+-------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

And finally a table to store titles and their related pay rates. If employees can be paid different rates for the same title, you wouldn't need the rate column here, instead you would use the rate stored in the `contracts_employees` table.

```
titles
    id                  varchar(15)(P)
    rate                double

+----------+-------+
| id       | rate  |
+----------+-------+
| Foreman  | 20.00 |
| Mechanic | 15.00 |
| ........ | ..... |
+----------+-------+
```

Comment: thanks @Benny Hill for your answer, I really appreciate your time into detail. I'll spend some time going over it and hopefully I'll be able to start making progress

Comment: @solleks - when it comes to database design just remember that normalization is (almost always) a good thing. Good luck!

Comment: @BennyHill: It looks like you have assumed that a "contract" _is a_ "job". When I read it, it sounded sort of like a contract could be comprised of several jobs (e.g. "you are contracted to perform jobs A, B, and C"). In my mind, there would be a `job` table with a `contract_id`, and then the employees would be assigned to a job, where their title and rate would be defined (i.e. two employees with the same title on the same job might not have the same rate). Then `contract_employees` turns into `job_employees` instead. Just some food for though, as I don't know if this was truly the intent.

Answer (score 2):

First thing, take a deep breath! It looks to me like you have a pretty good handle on this, maybe more than you think! This is not at all to try and design your project, and I'm sure you'll have lots of details to deal with, but maybe this will give an idea of how you might face these many many-to-many relationships swimming around in your head.

```
EMPLOYEES
---------
emp_id
emp_name
emp_address


JOBS
----
job_id
job_description


EMPLOYEE_JOBS
-------------
ej_id    -- primary key
emp_id   -- fk to employees table
job_id   -- fk to jobs table
ej_title -- employee title for this job
ej_rate  -- employee pay rate for this job


EMPLOYEE_JOB_HOURS
------------------
ejh_id  -- primary key
ej_id   -- fk to employee_jobs table
ejh_date
ejh_normal_hours  -- hours worked by the employee on this job on this date, etc.
ejh_overtime_hours
ejh_double_overtime_hours
```